# What is the alternative to putting UIWebView inside UIScrollView

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have gotten UIWebView inside UIScrollView to work, so far anyways, and I have just seen mention on Apple's site that doing so is not advised.

So OK, what's the alternative? I need to display web pages, and I need them to be scrollable, such that if the user swipes leftward then an entirely different page appears coming in from the right. And a reverse situation with swiping rightward.

How is that done without putting UIWebView inside UIScrollView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need the `UIWebView`, which has indeed many features of a `UIScrollView`, to be able to scroll not only up and down, but also to left and right.

Also, scrolling with two fingers is a no-go, for scrollable elements within a web page, such as `textarea`s can only be scrolled with two fingers.

Three fingers is also not so good because that's not convenient for people with thick fingers...

So my suggestion is that you add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your `UIWebView` and look out for a swipe gesture. Then handle the switching of pages accordingly with animations.

Comment: But can I actually slide one web page onto screen while sliding another off the screen using UIWebView?

Comment: I think for your specific problem, the approach is fine. Just make sure the app does not do any unexpected things.

Comment: I'm always on the lookout for unexpected things.